# Not null ForeignKey('self')

Tags: django, django-models

How can I make a ForeignKey refer back to the object itself? I'm trying :

```
Alias(MyBaseModel):
    type = models.ForeignKey('self')

a = Alias()
a.type = a
a.save()
```

But then when I run it :

```
(1048, "Column 'type_id' cannot be null")
```

I don't want the type to be null, I want it to contain its own ID. I have tons of objects, but only 1 loops back to itself, so I really don't want tot make it null. Ideas?

Comment: What does put() do? I've never seen that before.

Comment: sorry, it is a synonym to save. changed

Comment: Instead of type, you might want to use a non-python keyword :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you did `a.type = a`, a did not yet exist in the database, therefore it has no pk.

One way around this is to save twice, first to save it into the database, referring to a dummy object that's already in the database, then save it again once you can get it from the database.  One problem with this is there's sort of a chicken and egg problem of actually getting such an object into the database in the first place.  I'd deal with this by means of creating a fixture to run each time you use sync-db, so that one such object exists and is valid.

Another option is to relax the not-null constraint and be diligent about getting them assigned.

Either way, inserting into such a table will always be a pain because you can't get the PK to use without first inserting, and you can't insert without having a key to use in the reference field, regardless of ORM or database or anything.

an alternative solution is to break the circular dependency and do something like:

```
AliasType(django.db.Model):
    pass

Alias(MyBaseModel):
    type = models.ForeignKey(AliasType)

a = Alias()
a_t = AliasType()
a_t.save()
a.type = a_t
a.save()
```

You can still get useful information by using django's very smart accessors,

```
AliasType.objects.all()[0].alias_set
```

which can get you back to the original Alias object without having an explicit link to it.

Comment: Hmm, lots of options, sadly none of them look too good :( I went with the fixture. Created a file `fixtures/initial.json` which I figured out the format from `./manage.py dumpdata`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your type field be *null=True, blank=True*? Otherwise what is your base case?
I mean if you only have one object in the db what is it's type?

Having the object loop onto itself can be overcome by adopting a convention that an empty **type** field means exactly that - that object refers to itself!

If **type** field is not empty, that means it refers to another Alias object, which works out just peachy.

Your question does not make sense at the algorithmic level (unless i am missing something), so how can you make it work in db?

```
Alias(MyBaseModel):
    type = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)

a = Alias()
a.save()
# Now a refers to itself

b = Alias()
b.type = a
b.save()
# b does not refer to itself, but rather a
```

I know I redefined the problem a little, so sorry if that's not what you are after! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your input. If I change the blank case to mean myself, then I have to create a fetch method that returns the object itself when I try to render the type. The fixture solution seems to solve it a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

```
set null=true , blank=true in your code
like,

Alias(MyBaseModel):
    type = models.ForeignKey('self' , blank=True, null=True)

a = Alias()
a.type = a
a.save()
```